# Why are the images from Camera2API green?

Tags: android, android-camera2, capture

While using Camera2API in Android as `CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_OFF`, the images care coming with A LOT OF green, just like as if there is only a green channel.
The code I used is:

```java
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,Long.valueOf("2000000000"));
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY,200);
```

But when I set the `CameraMetadata` to `CONTROL_MODE_AUTO`, as in

```java
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
```

then the images are correct (not green).

Why is that and what must be done to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your own question, [the documentation for CONTROL_AWB_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AWB_MODE) says

> This control is only effective if android.control.mode is AUTO.

So `CONTROL_MODE_OFF` takes precedence over each individual control of 3A routines. If you need to disable just some of them, keeping the others in AUTO, use per-routine controls [CONTROL_AE_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_MODE), [CONTROL_AF_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AF_MODE) and [CONTROL_AWB_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AWB_MODE).

Comment: Thank you so much!!
Setting CONTROL_MODE to CONTROL_MODE_AUTO did its magic!